# Matlab class basics

Tags: matlab, class

I'm having some trouble creating classes in matlab and I don't really understand the method behind it (i'm fairly new to it)
here is my attempt at basic addition using matlab

> classdef test
>
> properties
>
> ```
>    a 
>    b
> ```
>
> end
>
> methods
>
> ```
>    function add = plus(a, b)
>    end
> ```
>
> end
>
> end

assigning values via

```
 p=test(), p.a=5
```

etc seems to work fine, however attempting `p.add`  returns the error

```
No appropriate method, property, or field add for class test.
```

Any help or guidance would be appretiated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods are defined exactly as functions are with respect to names and outputs.

Therefore, the method is called `plus`, the output the method should calculate is called `add`, and the way you probably wanted to write the method is:

```
function out = add(this)
     out = this.a + this.b;
end
```

Now you call the method as

```
p.add();
```